# YII - BOOTSTRAP Configuration Error?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I configure YII-BOOTSTRAP using these steps

http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html

But unable to configure & Get the below error, as shown below:[image] Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller.php is the base class for all controllers in Yii. Make sure you're autoloading it by having this in config.main

```
// autoloading model and component classes
import'=>array(
       ...
       'application.components.*',
       ....
),
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get you ? How should I write this in proper syntax ?

Comment: Just remove the dots (...) they are there to indicate to you not to remove the other elements already in that array.

Comment: Now it's give  this error ............

include(BController.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory